# Called by recruiter after final interview no offer nor rejection

Tags: interviewing

Recently went in for a final round interview. I thought it went well. The next day I was called by the recruiter and was told that I was well liked by the whole team, but that I was the first person they interviewed, so that the process would be delayed since they have to interview other candidates.

I was wondering if this is a good sign or neutral? Is this normal for a company to do? Do companies usually interview all eligible candidates before making a decision or do they sometimes go with the first person that works out?

Comment: Neutral. Normal. Continue interviewing elsewhere until they make you a real offer. See other answers on this site.

Comment: It's standard.  They interview all candidates in case the last person is a better fit than the first.

Answer (score 5):

As some of the comments have pointed out this is fairly neutral as a response goes. Depending on the company, even if you had completely blown them away and they wanted to hire you on the spot, internal policies could prevent it until all available candidates have been interviewed, or a minimum number of candidates have been considered. Also most government jobs are legally required to interview every available candidate, so again this would be standard.

It is encouraging that the recruiter told you that you were well liked - in my personal experience this *usually* bodes well. However, it is always worth it to keep your options open by continuing to look until you have a counter-signed offer (and even then keeping feelers out is usually a good idea).

Comment: Yes well-liked is a good sign, but I have interviewed where 3-4 people were ones I would have liked to hire but I only had one job opening, so never take it as a sign you will get the job.

Comment: @HLGEM I totally agree with you...nothing is ever guaranteed until you have a signed agreement.